# Removing toilet seat cover

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Does anybody know how to remove this type of toilet seat cover. i have no access to the underneath of the toilet as it is fixed to the wall. [image]i have tried to put a flat screw driver underneath and pop it out but it didnt work. I have also tried to lift the toilet seat off but couldn't move it.

Comment: Maybe a picture looking at the end of the hinge pins.  Might be an access plug or a way to pull/remove the pin acting like a hinge.

Comment: You say you have no access to underneath. Why is that? Reaching under the lip of the bowl (as shown in Tetsujin's answer below) is a very common approach. My experience is that US toilet seats are mounted to the bowl in the same manner.

Comment: I'm somewhat puzzled by it being attached to the wall preventing you from reaching underneath. Mine is attached to the wall too, & causes no issues.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica (and Tetsujin) You can get vertical sided toilets that give no access to underneath. They look neater. e.g. https://www.wickes.co.uk/Holkham-Easy-Clean-Rimless-Toilet-Pan-with-Soft-Close-Seat---Box-1-of-2/p/239576. Seats are screwed in from above using expanding plugs to hold them.

Comment: @AndyT - interesting, never seen one of those. We need more info from the OP really.

Comment: It could be one of the slide top ones like this. What does the back of the seat connection look like? : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toilet-Release-Adjustable-Hinges-Plastic/dp/B07Y7Z2VP3/ref=sr_1_4?c=ts&keywords=Toilet+Seats&qid=1658885677&refinements=p_n_shipping_option-bin%3A2023186031&s=diy&sr=1-4&ts_id=1938753031

Answer (score 1):

What country are you in?

British ones are almost always bolted through the porcelain from below - plastic bolts & nuts [or sometimes metal on older units] underneath near the ends of your base strip.
Sometimes, but not always, with a screw head accessible from the top [to hold the bolt still as you undo from underneath, you cannot unfasten it with just the screw],

From [WikiHow - How to Remove a Toilet Seat](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Toilet-Seat)

[image]

Comment: US ones are the same. Not having any wall mount toilets in my house (and never really being interested in crawling under one in any of the public restrooms that I usually see them mounted in), I can't _guarantee_ that they're held on the same way, but I can't fathom how or why they would be any different.

Comment: When fitting a toilet seat, you can trim the bolts to avoid having to screw the nut on for an extra ridiculous distance.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - or if you're as idle as I am, you can hold the nut & use a drill driver from above for most of the thread length;) Most of the ones I've fitted in the last decade or so, though, have segmented snap-off bolts, so you don't even need to cut them to size.

Comment: @Tetsujin Luxury! Next you'll be telling us you have a room for the toilet indoors so you don't have to wait for the spring thaw to use it ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I actually didn't until I was about 4. [I also, of course, 'ad to lick lake clean wi'me tonuge before I went to't pit'] You tell t' young 'uns of today & they don't believe a word of it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but my old toilet had two pins sticking up from the pan. These located into the hinge which gripped a groove on the aforementioned pins. To release, I simply pressed a button on the hinge. It was a little stiff and looked like it was just there for decoration. My button was in the center (on the back face of the hinge) and could only be accessed when the seat was down.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to say from that image. But based on my own experience (UK, toilets which give no access to underneath): if you can't see an obvious way to disconnect it, you probably just have to pull upwards hard until it pops off.

You'll then be able to unscrew the bolts that hold a connector bar onto the toilet pan.